# UWP MediaPlayerElement weird Play button appearance when MediaTransportContols.IsCompact is True

Tags: uwp

How can I show a correct play button of compact MediaPlayerElement in version 1903?

The below image is a normal play button of MediaPlayerElement on which the mouse pointer (not captured) is.

[image]

The below image is in the case of this code, just a COMPACT view.

```
<MediaPlayerElement AreTransportControlsEnabled="True">
    <MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
        <MediaTransportControls IsCompact="True"/>
    </MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
</MediaPlayerElement>
```

[image]

The only play button has a  weird appearance which doesn't have the bottom border. Any other buttons are appropriate as follows.

[image]

Comment: tried your code. it works for COMPACT view perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. I checked the template of the MediaTransportControls. It shows the play button is not the original play button when the mode isn't in compact mode. It's a button called **PlayPauseButtonOnLeft** that will be hidden when the MediaPlayerElement is the normal mode.

If you want to change this behavior, you could re-template the transport control, change the style or the position of the button.
Here is the document that you could refer to [Customize the transport controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls#customize-the-transport-controls)